# Get checked values from Listview in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin as well as for the C#. I have a listview in my app and I am binding data through ItemsSource. I have a checkbox inside the listview. I am using Xamarin.Forms.InputKit. What I want is to access/get all checked row data via ViewModel. Data binding works well. I tried with **CheckChangedCommand**, but it is not triggering inside the ViewModel.

ListView....

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LifeDemandList}" x:Name="lDemandView" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout HeightRequest="44" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Vertical">

                    <Grid Padding="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="{Binding quicksandsFont}" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding DEMAND}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="{Binding quicksandsFont}" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding PREMIUM}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="2">
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="{Binding quicksandsFont}" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding LATEFEE}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="3">
                            <input:CheckBox  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsChecked="{Binding ROWCHECK}" Type="Check"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Sample data binding via ViewModel.

```
    List<LifeDemandData> lList = new List<LifeDemandData>();

    LifeDemandData ldd = new LifeDemandData();
    ldd.DEMAND = "2019/03";
    ldd.PREMIUM = "2,000.00";
    ldd.LATEFEE = "10.00";
    ldd.ROWCHECK = false;
    lList.Add(ldd);

    LifeDemandData ldd1 = new LifeDemandData();
    ldd1.DEMAND = "2019/04";
    ldd1.PREMIUM = "11,896.00";
    ldd1.LATEFEE = ".00";
    ldd1.ROWCHECK = false;
    lList.Add(ldd1);

    LifeDemandList = lList;
```

Comment: thankz for the response. but how to achieve this in the ViewModel? Because **CheckChangedCommand** not trigger in the ViewModel.

Comment: Why are u using that many stack layouts really no need at all

Comment: @csharpdude77 this was my early days with Xamarin Forms. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can set the event **CheckChanged** of the checkbox and get all checked row data .

> in xaml

```
<input:CheckBox  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsChecked="{Binding ROWCHECK , Mode=TwoWay}" Type="Check" CheckChanged="CheckBox_CheckChanged"/>
```

> in code behind

For example I implement it in the contentPage

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData> LifeDemandList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData> selectedList;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;



        LifeDemandList = new ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData>()
        {
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/01" , LATEFEE = "22,000" , PREMIUM = "10.00" , ROWCHECK = false },
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/02" , LATEFEE = "11,987" , PREMIUM = ".00" , ROWCHECK = false },
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/03" , LATEFEE = "12,456" , PREMIUM = "6.00" , ROWCHECK = false },
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/04" , LATEFEE = "78,159" , PREMIUM = "3.00" , ROWCHECK = false },

        };

        listview.ItemsSource = LifeDemandList;

    }

    private void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedList = new ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData>();

        for (int i=0;i< LifeDemandList.Count;i++)
        {
            LifeDemandData item = LifeDemandList[i];

            if(item.ROWCHECK)
            {
                selectedList.Add(item);
            }
        }

        DisplayAlert("Title", selectedList.Count + " item have been selected", "Cancel");

        // do something you want 

    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to implement it in **ViewModel**

> in xaml

```
<input:CheckBox  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsChecked="{Binding ROWCHECK , Mode=TwoWay}" Type="Check" CheckChangedCommand="{Binding CheckedCommand}" />
```

> in model

```
public class LifeDemandData
{
    public string DEMAND { get; set; }
    public string PREMIUM { get; set; }
    public string LATEFEE { get; set; }
    public bool ROWCHECK { get; set; }
    public ICommand CheckedCommand {  set; get; }

}
```

> in ViewModel

```
 public class MyViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData> LifeDemandList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData> selectedList;

    ICommand MyCommand;

    public MyViewModel()
    {

        MyCommand = new Command(() =>
        {


            selectedList = new ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData>();

            for (int i = 0; i < LifeDemandList.Count; i++)
            {
                LifeDemandData item = LifeDemandList[i];

                if (item.ROWCHECK)
                {
                    selectedList.Add(item);
                }
            }

           App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Title", selectedList.Count + " item have been selected", "Cancel");

        });

        LifeDemandList = new ObservableCollection<LifeDemandData>()
        {
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/01" , LATEFEE = "22,000" , PREMIUM = "10.00" , ROWCHECK = false , CheckedCommand=MyCommand},
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/02" , LATEFEE = "11,987" , PREMIUM = ".00" , ROWCHECK = false , CheckedCommand=MyCommand},
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/03" , LATEFEE = "12,456" , PREMIUM = "6.00" , ROWCHECK = false , CheckedCommand=MyCommand},
           new LifeDemandData{ DEMAND = "2019/04" , LATEFEE = "78,159" , PREMIUM = "3.00" , ROWCHECK = false , CheckedCommand=MyCommand },

        };           

    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: thankz for the response. but how to achieve this in the ViewModel?  Because **CheckChangedCommand** not trigger in the ViewModel.

Comment: I checked your code in code behind, working great. What I want. If you can please help with ViewModel. Thanks I will upvote

Comment: This seems like a very hacky way to bind the command. The problem is that the `BindingContext` inside the `DataTemplate` will be set the the listitem, so it never knows to look for the property on the ViewModel. To be able to bind to a property of the ViewModel we can just reference the `ListView` and take it's BindingContext as source: `CheckChangedCommand={Binding Source={x:Reference lDemandView}, Path=BindingContext.CheckChangedCommand}`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, Hi, your both answers are working well. I just wanna know how to pass **object sender** parameter that in **CheckBox_CheckChanged** to **Command(() =>** in view model. because i wanna know about the check box which i am clicking

Comment: Why not show ur xaml obv its differnt to the op am lost how to show the xaml for your solution to this. Please edit with the xaml if stil have it